# SQL: Getting a row for each passing month up to date

Tags: sql

I have a table that stores defects.
Each defect has a detection date and a closing date.

I want to extract the info for each month up to current date, about the number of open defects in that month.

For example, lets assume these are all the defects I have in my DB:

```
defect 1 - Detected in (01-01-2014)  , Closed in (04-03-2014)
defect 2 - Detected in (07-02-2014)  , Closed in (null) (still open)
```

I'd like to extract the info as follows:

```
01-01-2014 - 1 open defect  (defect 1 was created)
01-02-2014 - 2 open defects (defect 2 was created)
01-03-2014 - 1 open defect  (defect 1 was closed this month)
01-04-2014 - 1 open defect  (defect 2 was never closed so I would get entries up to today)
...
...
01-02-2015 - 1 open
```

Is there a way to get this info with a single query without using functions?

Comment: I can't picture how without having a table containing a list of dates. Even then, the single query would likely be more cumbersome than the functions you are avoiding. Indeed, the "single" query would likely involve at least a couple of sub-queries.

Comment: A few questions - 
If it is by month, shouldn't it be only month and year in the result? (Because on 1/2/14, there was only 1 open, 2nd came on 7th)

Which RDBMS is it? MySQL, PostgreSQL, Sql Server, etc?

What is the schema like?

Comment: Does this text: `defect 1 - Detected in (01-01-2014)  , Closed in (04-03-2014)` is saved in a single column?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding the question of "why no functions", it is possible to go N months back (limits apply) with the query below.  Just replace "16" in "WHERE n < 16" with the number of months back you want to evaluate

```
; WITH Numbers (n) AS (
    SELECT  1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  n + 1
    FROM    Numbers
    WHERE   n < 16
)
, NextMonth (dt) AS (
    SELECT  CAST( CAST( DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR ) + '-' + CAST( DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())+1 AS VARCHAR ) + '-1' AS DATETIME )
)
, PriorMonths (dt) AS (
    SELECT  DATEADD( MONTH, -1 * n, dt )
    FROM    NextMonth
    CROSS JOIN Numbers
), RawData ( y, m, DateOpened ) AS (
    SELECT  DATEPART( YEAR, dt )
    ,       DATEPART( MONTH, dt )
    ,       t.DateOpened
    FROM    PriorMonths AS pm
    LEFT JOIN    @t AS t
        ON  DATEADD(MONTH,-1,t.DateOpened) < dt
        AND (DATEADD(MONTH,-1,t.DateClosed) >= dt OR t.DateClosed IS NULL)
)
SELECT  y, m, COUNT(DateOpened)
FROM    RawData
GROUP BY y, m
ORDER BY y DESC, m DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

First I want to point out that I've used MS SQL Server T-SQL functions `DATEADD()`, `DATEDIFF()`, and `GETDATE()` - there should be equivalents in whatever flavour of SQL you want to use.

The variable `@startDate` should be set to the start of the range on which you want to report.

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE;
DECLARE @endDate DATE;
SET @startDate = '20140101';
SET @endDate = DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0);

WITH Dates (dEnd, dStart) AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(M, 1, @endDate), @endDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(M, -1, dEnd), DATEADD(M, -1, dStart)
    FROM    Dates
    WHERE   dEnd > @startDate
)
SELECT dStart AS 'Month start', COUNT(Defects.reportedDate) AS 'Open defects'
FROM Dates
LEFT OUTER JOIN Defects ON 
    Defects.reportedDate < dEnd AND (Defects.resolvedDate IS NULL OR Defects.resolvedDate > dStart)
GROUP BY dStart
ORDER BY dStart;
```